# How to set the Ubuntu Python3 interpreter path in VS Code?

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Python3 on Ubuntu 20.04 inside WSL2, running `print(sys.executable)` outputs `/usr/bin/python3`

Within VS Code, pressing "Select Interpreter" then "Enter Interpreter Path" I have tried both `/usr/bin/python3` and the full windows path `\\wsl$\Ubuntu/\usr\bin/python3` (which is reachable inside file explorer).

Both paths returns the error `An Invalid Python interpreter is selected, please try changing it to enable features such as IntelliSense, linting, and debugging.`

It seems to only accept an .exe file, how can I select the Linux path as the interpreter? Thanks.

Comment: Where do you run VS Code? Native or in WSL?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Natively, installed at C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like either:

- You are starting VSCode from Windows, rather than from inside WSL
- Or you don't have the WSL extension installed
- Or both

There are several options for doing WSL development in VSCode, but all do require that you start by installing (if you haven't already) either:

- The "Remote - WSL" extension
- Or the "Remote Development" extension pack, which includes the former

Then, typically, you'll start VSCode by navigating to your project directory in WSL and:

```
code .
```

You'll see that VSCode has switched from "Windows" mode to "WSL" mode in the lower left-hand corner of the status-bar, where you should see *"WSL: [distroname]"*.

With that in place, you should be able to select the *Linux* Python interpreter.

Alternatively, you can start VSCode through Windows, then switch to WSL mode with the stacked "><" icon in that same location on the status-bar.  Or just enter the command-palette and *"Remote-WSL: New WSL Window"*.